# Arduino Nano + HM-10 module not receiving data on mobile

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

wondering if anyone would know why is this happening.
I have HM-10 Bluetooth module that is connected to Arduino. I use [Serial Bluetooth Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_bluetooth_terminal&hl=cs) for communicating with the HM-10 module.

The code below works perfectly fine with Arduino **UNO**,

1. the LED is turned ON/OFF
2. I receive messages in Serial monitor
3. I receive messages on my mobile phone

However if I use the same sketch and the same scheme with Arduino **NANO**

1. the LED is turned ON/OFF
2. I receive messages in Serial monitor

I do NOT receive any message on my mobile phone. I tried almost all other pins including the `TX1` & `RX0`pins but without any luck. It simply doesn't send any data to the `RXD` pin of the HM-10 module.

Is this some kind of limitation of Arduino Nano or do I have a faulty one?

[image: connection scheme]

```
// Arduino Bluetooth modul HM-10
#define RX 11
#define TX 10
#define pinLED 13

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(TX, RX);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Arduino on");  
  bluetooth.begin(9600);
  bluetooth.print("Arduino ON");

  pinMode(pinLED, OUTPUT);  
}

void loop() {

  byte BluetoothData;

  if (bluetooth.available() > 0) {

    BluetoothData=bluetooth.read();

    switch (BluetoothData) {      
      case '0':        
        digitalWrite(pinLED, LOW);        
        Serial.println("LED turned OFF");
        bluetooth.println("LED turned OFF");
        break;
      case '1':        
        digitalWrite(pinLED, HIGH);        
        Serial.println("LED turned ON");
        bluetooth.println("LED turned ON");
        break;      
      default:        
        Serial.println("Unknown command");
        bluetooth.println("Unknown command");
    }
  }  
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: Try  swapping RX and TX, Rx from one device is supposed to be connected to the TX of the other device.

Comment: Thanks @GrooverFromHolland Already tried and just in case I tried again. Unfortunately not working. I even try to just connect Nano TX to Bluettoth RX (leaving Bluetooth TX connected to Nano D10) then unplugged the USB to allow Nano to send data to the Bluetooth RX but still no data received on my phone. After reading a lot yesterday & today I think that I simply chose wrong board to work with